# How to Support Facebook SDK for Unity on Mobile Platforms, Without having Facebook Canvas?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook-unity-sdk to for getting list of users friends. 
but i am not being able to get any data.

i also tried open graph explorer to fire graph API

the results were as follows[image]

Is there a way i could use some Graph API endpoint other then "invitable_friends" to retrieve list of all friends of user?

Comment: invitable_friends are there so you can invite friends and not so you can get a list for friends. /me/friends will return your friends

Comment: but this will only give me list of friends who already installed the app, right ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. there is no other endpoint.

well.. as far as i understood your question you can do one thing.

Just add a platform(app on facebook) in your app settings, and when it asks you about "Canvas URL" just put any random website URL and save settings.

now check if the "invitable_friends" is working or not.

PS:-

You don't have to run by the rules every time. :)

Comment: that really did the trick, thanks.  +1 for "not to run by the rules"